# Protect the Arduino make with Unique Id

Tags: arduino-uno

I’d like to protect my arduino make with a unique serial number for every device I make.
What are the proper ways to do it? Probably there are kind of best practices…
Keep it in EEPROM is obviously a bad idea.

I believe that there is some chip that can be added to the circuitry.

The general idea is the following.
Circuitry has a hardware which gives a unique id (serial number). Distributor/seller generates the signature using unique id and put it to the eeprom. Arduino program verifies this signature using hardware serial number. Arduino program is distributed in binary or within the device.

Comment: Why is EEPROM a bad idea for this?

Comment: Because it can be rewritten easily.

Comment: And even with an extra chip, the sketch on the Arduino needs to send read and send the ID of the device. One could easily change the sketch to not send the ID from the extra chip, but a custom one. Unless you connect the extra chip directly to the external device or you use encryption, it is still possible to change. What are you trying here? Is it a safety measure, so that no one temperes with your device? Or do you just want to prevent to accidentially override it?

Comment: @chrisl, I distribute hex only, no sources. Since that nobody can alter the sketch. I am trying to protect my hex from easy copying.

Comment: *"Since that nobody can alter the sketch."* This is plain wrong. It is no problem to decompile hex dumps of several KB, especially if you know the hardware. I've done that multiple times.

Comment: @thebusybee, so, what do you suggest?

Comment: It depends on *why* and *against what* you want protection.

Comment: @thebusybee If you can read assembler code, you are elite, I believe. But simple farmer can’t. Disassembling requires special intelligence.  However, a humble farmer is able to install Arduino IDE and follow some simple instructions. But he won’t ever disassemble the hex, alter it and compile it again.

Comment: @thebusybee I want to have a reasonable protection of my makes from copying without purchasing.

Comment: Then your external chip has to contain a cypher algorithm that will be feeded by an identifier from your sketch. That chip has to be serialized so that different chips will return different results on the same identifier. The chip must have protection against reading it. -- Only the correct identifier will produce some values that are urgently needed to run the sketch. This could be some machine code parts of a kernal. Without this values it wont run.

Comment: *But beware!* Don't just return a boolean saying "OK/Error". It far too simple to patch that single instruction to disable the protection scheme. Such a patch will spread much faster than you can call "Stop!" -- And you have to think about what to do if some curious guy reveals the secret contents and publishes it. This already happened, I watched it, and will happen again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101123/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-zhekaus).

Answer (score 2):

I still suggest using the eeprom.
It is the firmware's job to handle whether or not data in eeprom can be written.
You could implement wrapper functions for the arduino which can only read/write after a defined offset. You can set this read-only data with the .eep-file when you upload your sketch. The eeprom file then may be generated programmatically.

Once you have to flash several individual devices with a final firmware version, there are no benefits in using the arduino ide. You can upload the firmware and the eeprom file using avrdude:

```
avrdude -P YOUR_PORT -b 115200 -p ATmega328P -e -U flash:w:YOUR_FIRMWARE.hex -U eeprom:w:YOUR_EEPROM.eep
```

It's up to you how to generate the eeprom file (bash/batch, make, pyhton,...).

Comment: Sounds interesting! Can you add an example how to use it?

Comment: I don't get it. Anybody can upload eeprom file from another arduino. I want to protect my devices from copying.

Comment: @zhekaus doesn't the upload work? You have to run the command from the build directory. You may have to select a programmer, but I think avrdude would force you. The simplest to get an eeprom file to start with might be to initialize the eeprom with temporary firmware which stores the desired values and then read-back the .eep-file using the above command with `eeprom:r:initial.eep`.

Comment: @zhekaus also, what do you mean by "protect my devices from copying"? An attacker would be able to read or write any unencrypted data the same way you do anyway.

Comment: nobody asks how to upload eeprom. Let's stick to the initial question, please ))

Comment: attacker does not know how to verify this unencrypted data. Official distributor does. PS. How to @ your nickname, Sim Son?

Comment: @zhekaus select an respond to comment for the '@' or type it manually (no spaces)

Comment: Sim Sin, of course, I know it. But stackexchange does not allow this with your two-word nickname ))

Comment: My general idea is: Circuitry has a hardware which gives unique id (serial number). Distributor/seller generates the signature using unique id. Arduino program verifies this signature using hardware serial number. Signature is stored in eeprom. Arduino program is distributed like binary.

Comment: Hmm, I can't read that in your question, but now I got it due to the comments. "Hidden in data" is not the same as "encrypted" and therefore storing such information at dedicated addresses in flash means no security. You can encrypt the information beforehand, but if it's encrypted you can use the eeprom.

Comment: I don’t understand your proposal. Anybody can copy hex and eeprom from one Arduino to another. Where is the protection here? It does not mattet whether it's encrypted or not.
However, nobody can copy DS2401.

Comment: Anyone who hooks up some wires can read the ds2401.

Comment: Maybe he can read. But can he forge? Allrighty, anyway, when we talk about the protection, we always keep in mind the cost of breaching it. Certainly, nobody believes in absolutely robust security. The question is in the cost of breeching. Yeah, probably DS2401 is not a good idea, but at least, it already looks like much better than simple keeping unique id in eeprom, since anybody can copy it with avrdude.

Comment: Then hacker will do it the same way old DOS games was cracked - dowload and debug the hex - overwrite the function reading DS2401 to not read it and return correct value insted, then distribute the modified hex. Anybody can download it, burn it and whether they have or not the DS2401, the function will return correct result and the Arduino will work the same way, the original one worked. Needs one "elite hacker" and internet copy to work on as many Arduinos as its users wants. That said, I do not think that this approach is working nor the best possible one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way! I can use DS2401 or DS2411.

These devices are 64-bit read only memory (ROM) "silicon serial number" devices which are programmed by the manufacturer with a unique 48 bit serial number, an 8 bit product family code, and an 8 bit CRC.

Comment: it can be removed, replaced

Comment: If it's removed, device won't work. Also, I suppose to keep a signature in eeprom which will be verified with unique id. If it’s not verified, device won’t work.

Comment: @zhekaus (See my comment at your question,too.) Since your sketch can be decompiled it is no problem to work around any protection you implemented.

Comment: @thebusybee You are right. But it requires extra skills, much more advances than avrdude using. My makes are not rocket science. I simply want to have a reasonable protection, nothing fancy or extremely robust.